# При нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает android-toast

Tags: android-studio, android-toast

При нажатии на кнопку должно появляться уведомление с текстом и картинкой.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void showToast(View view) {
    Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.learnjava, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast3.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    LinearLayout toastContainer = (LinearLayout) toast3.getView();
    ImageView javaImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    javaImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.java_logo);
    toastContainer.addView(javaImageView, 0);
    toast3.show();
}
```

Но при нажатии приложение вылетает и в logcat появляются такие ошибки:

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.notification_java.MainActivity.showToast(MainActivity.java:27)

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Попробовал. Работает.

Comment: Из-за чего может возникать такая ошибка?

Comment: Может импорт неправильный, у меня вот так: `import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;` Нажатие на кнопку как обрабатываете? Строчка и картинка точно есть?

Comment: Да, текст и картинка точно добавлены